The motto of the Indian Army 'Seva Parmo Dharma' is derived from which hindu scripture exactly?
I tried searching the web for answers, but it doesn't seem to have one, expect for some claiming that it's a verse from the Bhagvada Gita, but failing to cite the exact chapter and verse.

Just because there is a popular Saṁskṛta phrase in current-day, doesn't necessarily mean it's śāstriya.
As Saṁskṛta is a properly functional lang., you can create innumerable no. of cogent vākyas in it.
